# Can someone explain the logic to me it seems both are equal

Tags: java

Can someone explain me the logic why a and b are both equal and x and y are not both equal but they have the same value.

```
Integer a = 40;`// integer a 
Integer b =40; // integer b
Integer x = 400; // why x and y are not equal
Integer y = 400; // how is that possible

if (a==b){  //first condition 
   System.out.println("a=b");  //if true print
}else {
   System.out.println("a!=b"); // if not true 
}

if(x==y){  // second condition 
   System.out.println("x=y"); // if true print 
}else{
   System.out.println("x!y"); // if not true print
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `==` to compare objects. Either use `x.intValue()`, compare them with `.equals()` or create them as the primitive type `int` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

it is a mistake to compare objects (or really a bad practice) with the ==, for that most of the objects overwrite the `compareTo()` , and obvious the `Intege` is not the exception.

Comment: or in any case the equals()